# Mac Store - Invalid Binary on iTunesConnect - the signature is invalid

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect, mac-app-store, codesign

iTunesConnect seem to be rejecting our binaries (for the Mac App Store) now with the following error

> **Invalid Signature** - the main app bundle wetfm at path wetfm.app is signed but the signature is invalid. The following error(s) were reported from codesign:
>
> a sealed resource is missing or invalid
> In architecture: i386

I've spent the last several days now looking into this and have tried just about everything; the output from `codesign --verify -vvvv wetfm.app` is

> wetfm.app: valid on disk
> wetfm.app: satisfies its designated requirement

From `codesign --display --verbose=4 wet.fm.app` I get the full list of output headers, including `Authority=3rd Party Developer Application: our company cert`; which seems to indicate it has been signed correctly.

The application is being built on the commandline (not XCode -- using Unity3D) using `codesign -vvvv -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: our company...' --entitlements wetfm.entitlements wetfm.app`; then two plugin bundles and a framework are being signed using a similar command afterwards.

Finally the package is being built with `productbuild --component "wetfm.app" "/Applications" --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: our company..." wetfmpackage.pkg` - which is then being submitted through Application Loader (which accepts it, uploads, then the invalid signature email is sent to us.)

So far, I've tried all the following:

- Revoking all our developer certificates, regenerating them within XCode (and seperately via the Developer Certificates site)
- Deleting all provisioning profiles
- Re-arranging the order of the signing process (signing the main bundle first, last)
- Signing or not signing the sub bundles (which come up as additional errors later if they are not)
- Adding 'application-identifier' to the entitlements file (caused Application Loader to reject upload)
- Renaming the app and bundleIDs (from wet.fm to wetfm)
- Trying to upload to a new (different) app on iTunesConnect

As best I can tell, it does appear to be being signed correctly locally - it'd be extremely useful if I could get codesign to at least output the same error message as the one being emailed back; as that would make testing significantly faster.

If anyone has any clues or insights, it'd be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

(Environment: 10.8.2, latest versions of everything.)

Comment: Just make sure that the provisioning profile is build for Distribution-App Store build.

Comment: So, as a follow up to this - days of annoyance later. Here's how I got it fixed; hopefully this will be of use to someone else who encounters this.

Unity3D was adding a couple of hidden files to the directory when building - I suspect this is because we're building the Mac binaries under Windows, but regardless of the cause; it has placed a couple of files named, e.g. '._unity default resources' inside the .app. Now;

Comment: It appears codesign ignores those when verifying, but not when signing. packagebuild ignores them when building. So; the app verifies fine, and the package builds fine -- but if you install the package, then try verify where you just installed to, you'll get the "a sealed resource is missing or invalid" which iTunesConnect rejects the binary with.

Now to go light people on fire...

Comment: Adam, it'd be great to put your finding as an answer, rather than a comment on your question. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question on StackOverflow.